Mermaid not rendering graph
I am trying to change a mermaid graph on demand using the following code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/10.8.0/mermaid.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
  <div id="mermaid" class="mermaid" markdown="0" >
   graph TD;
    A((Editable Node)) --> B((Node));
    B --> C((Node));
    C --> D((Editable Node));
    click A "Edit Node A" "javascript:editNode(config, 'A')";
    click D "javascript:editNode(config, 'flowchart-D-5')";  
  </div>
</div>
  <script>
    const config = {
      securityLevel:'loose',
        theme: 'base',
        startOnLoad: true,
        };
       mermaid.initialize(config);

      function editNode(config, id) {

        
        var node = document.getElementById(id);
        var newValue = prompt("Enter new value:", node.textContent);
        if (newValue !== null && newValue.trim() !== "") {
            node.textContent = newValue.trim();

        var merm = document.getElementById("mermaid");
        merm.setAttribute('data-processed','false');
        mermaid.init(config, ".mermaid");
   }
  }
</script>

 </body>
</html>


All works fine until when I try to change the text of a node e.x. the last one. Then the node disappears.
graph before node change
graph after node change
What is wrong with the code?
I have spent many hours trying to find a solution but to no avail.

Have you tried this where the two nodes do not have the same text?
